# Multiple selected onkeydown selectbox javascript

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

i have a input field for searching in multiple selectbox, i want when i search more than 1 value using comma(,) as delimiter, the index of multiple selectbox are selected. like this [image]

i have try this code, but not working

Search input

```
<input id="idSearch" name="txtSearch" size="50" onkeydown="cekKey(event,document.frmAdd.selNonMember,document.frmAdd.selMember);" type="Text">
```

left selectbox

```
<select name="selNonMember" multiple size="8" style="width:100%">
    <cfloop query="QEmp">
        <option value="#QEmp.Emp_id#"> #HtmlEditFormat(QEmp.Text)# </option>
    </cfloop>
</select>
```

cekKey()

```
function cekKey(event,objSource,objTarget)
    {
        <!--- tekan enter --->
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            addSelEmp()
            event.returnValue = false;
            document.frmAdd.txtSearch.value = ''
        } else {
            event.returnValue = true;
        }
    }

    function addSelEmp() {
        var searchKey = document.frmAdd.txtSearch.value;
        var objSource = document.frmAdd.selNonMember;
        var objTarget = document.frmAdd.selMember;
        //var vari1 = document.frm.txtSearchEmp.value;
        searchKey = searchKey.toUpperCase()

        for(i = objSource.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {  

            var vari2 = objSource.options[i].text;
            vari2 = vari2.toUpperCase();

            if(vari2.indexOf(searchKey) >= 0) {
                //objTarget.options[objTarget.length] = new Option(vari2,objSource.options[i].value);
                objSource.options[i].selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I used to use that plugin before, but I now use Select2. It has better fallback support and it easier to customize. http://select2.github.io/

Comment: The term `not working` is too vague.  Please elaborate.

Comment: @DanBracuk the value was not selected when users input more than 1 value, in this case when i type 20160950010,20160950020, the options was not selected, not like the pic above. but when the users input only 1 value like 20160950010, the options was selected. thats make me frustate